# Colour profiles not working thoughout

Tags: gnome, colors, 22.10

During the installation of the update from 23.04 to 22.10, the installer crashed.
I managed to rescue the situation and update it to 23.10, however, this section of Gnome does not change the colour profile with the rest of the GUI.
I don't know why it is green - a colour I have never used. Changing to any other colour in system preferences will amend the folder colours but this remains green.

On a separate upgrade on my laptop, this works fine.

Does anyone know which files are missing or corrupt that require reinstall or any configs stuck in read-only mode that prevents this changing colour?

[image]